# EF API POST Insert with FK tables how to Insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, entity-framework-6

I'm taking input info from a React front end.  I need to write an insert API call to do this.  Right now I have the main table insert working but none of the related tables are getting new data - course not sending any data to insert anyway. If I do a GET I get the following:

```html
 "AR_Reliability": [],
        "AR_SafetyAndHealth": [],
        "ASR_Environmental": [],
        "ASR_MOC": [],
        "CR_OperationsProblems": [],
        "CR_ProcessControls": [],
        "FR_Bypasses_Opened": [],
        "FR_Dual_Pumps_Running": [],
        "FR_EquipmentMaintenance": [],
        "FR_OperationsProblems": [],
        "PSR_OperatingConstraints": [],
        "PSR_OperatingTargets": [],
        "PSR_OperationsProblems": [],
        "Report_ID": 1,
        "RoadClosures": "Test_Rc",
        "FirstMaintainStart": "Test_Fms",
        "PSR_AbnormalOperations": "Test_Ao",
        "FeedstockChanges": "Test_Fsc",
        "LineupChanges": "Test_Lc",
        "SafetyMeetings": "Test_Sm   ",
        "CR_AbnormalOperations": "Test_Ao",
        "HighPriorityAlarms": "Test_Hpa",
        "Impairment_to_fire_protection_systems": "Test_Ifp",
        "AlarmsInhibited": "Test_Ai",
        "FR_AbnormalOperations": "Test_Ao",
        "Maintenance": "Test_Mt   ",
        "CreatedDate": "2019-01-08T00:00:00",
        "UpdatedDate": "2019-01-08T00:00:00",
        "CreatedBy": "Dev                                               ",
        "UpdatedBy": "Dev                                               ",
        "Shift": "1    ",
        "Area_ID": 1,
        "User_ID": 1
```

So these other FK related tables it looks like are represented by Arrays.
Doing and insert using EF do I only needed to receive a EF main table object from React?   I'm clueless about React but have been tasked with the API part.  Will the EF automatically add data to these auxillary arrays as part of the SaveChanges() call?

Comment: If you want to know, how things are done right, do Research, try it on your own and If you get an error, Provide your best, Not working attempt! This is NOT a Code Providing Platform!

Comment: So please at least add your current API-Controller-Code.

Answer (score 0):

if the table has a constraint on another table, you have to insert data into the constraining table first.  When you go to insert into the main table the FK has to exist.

So like if user_ID 1 is a key to a user table it has to already exist for this AR_Reliability insert to work.

Comment: public bool AddReport(Forms_Reports report)
        {

            ctx.Forms_Reports.Add(report);
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }

Comment: EF is supposed to take care of that but when a new record inserted it is not inserting a new record into the auxiliary tables.  The auxiliary tables allow null for all fields but the Primary key.  The ReportID FK can also be NULL  which i think is incorrect because the only way this table should even exist is to have data related to a ReportID.  I'll keep researching.............